# "undefined reference to" (function) & "in archive is not an object" Android ndk-build

Tags: android, curl, build, android-ndk

I'll expose my problem quickly. I am trying to port curl on Android and to use it within my app. I built the curl library with the ARM toolchain, configured and made (a couple times to make sure I didn't do nothing wrong the first time).

I then proceeded to put the newly created libcurl.a and my curljni.c into my jni folder, as long as the following Android.mk :

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= libcurl
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libcurl.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/curl
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := curljni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := curljni.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/curl
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libcurl
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I've been trying a lot of things and I'm pretty sure it looks good now, but whenever I try to build with the ndk-build tool I obtain the following :

[image]

Note : curljni.c makes calls to functions within the libcurl library and its easy.h and curl.h files. They are then included in top of the file.

I also tried to ask for the whole library to get loaded into my Android app, using LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES instead of LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES, but without much more success :

[image]

Previously :

- Downloaded curl.7.28.0
- Made a standalone toolchain for ARM 4.6
- Fixed several files within curl whose linebreaks were DOS like and needed Unix like (bug in configure) - one of which was depcomp, linked to libcurl_la-file.lo
- ./configure --host=arm-linux-androidaebi --with-zlib --enable-ipv6
- make/make install
- Added the resulting libcurl.a from curl\lib.libs

Comment: I used a downloaded .a file and it worked. But yet I don't get what was the error with my own .a build.

Comment: The "member ... in archive is not an object" and undefined reference (i.e. symbol not found) problems sound like an architecture problem, i.e. double check the way you build libcurl so that the static library includes `armeabi` object files. In particular make sure it uses the compiler from your Android toolchain (see slides 34, 35 and 36 here: https://speakerdeck.com/deltheil/running-native-code-on-android-number-osdcfr-2012).

Comment: I didn't specify the CC and CXX when using the cross-toolchain (yet used the SYSROOT and BUILD), I'll give it a go when I have time to do so. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
Your Problem is that your library libcurl.a is not builded with Android ndk gcc ..
You have done :

```
$ ./configure --host=arm-linux-androidaebi --with-zlib --enable-ipv6
$ make
$ make install
```

this will generate a library using your PC gcc ..NOt good .

---

What i do is to configure open source library l for android using line command (or like you have done):

```
 ./configure --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=arm-linux-androideabi --target=arm-linux-androideabi
```

But then you schould not call make and make install  ! .

You have to create an android.mk whinch will compile all source file in your  libcurl  + your jni file   ' curljni.c'  and put all in one lib : here an example of Android.mk compiling SQLITE3

```
###################################################
# SQLITE3
###################################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := Mysqlite3
MY_LOCAL_SQLITE_SRC := $(LOCAL_PATH)/sqlite/

LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -g
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -I $(MY_LOCAL_SQLITE_SRC)


 LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES:=$(MY_LOCAL_SQLITE_SRC)

FILE_LIST :=$(wildcard $(MY_LOCAL_SQLITE_SRC)*.c*)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

# My SQLITE3 JNI FILE 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES +=mysqlite_jni.cpp

# include native  NDK library  liblog and libz 
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```